# Am using stored procedure in SQL and retrieving data into my Data Grid View but am having a problem at this point

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following code:

```
AS

    BEGIN

    SELECT 
        p.[ProductID] 
        ,l1.[Description] AS 'Category'
        ,l2.[Description] AS 'Supplier Name'
        ,p.[PurchasePrice] AS 'Purchase Price'
        ,p.[SalesPrice] AS 'Sales Price'
        ,l3.[Description] AS 'Sizes'

from [dbo].[Productss] p
INNER JOIN [dbo].[ListTypesData] l1 ON p.CategoryID = l1.ListTypeDataID
INNER JOIN [dbo].[ListTypesData] l2 ON p.SupplierName = l2.ListTypeDataID
INNER JOIN [dbo].[ProductSizes] ps ON p.ProductID = ps.[ProductID]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[ListTypesData] l3 ON ps.[SizeID] = l3.ListTypeDataID


    END
```

And I'm getting this error:

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'khurram' to data type int

Comment: Without knowing the table definitions involved (including the DDL for the relevant tables is often useful for this sort of question), you're joining `[Productss]` and `[ListTypesData]` on `[SupplierName] = [ListTypeDataID]`. The column names would suggest that `[SupplierName]` is probably a textual value (i.e. an `NVARCHAR` such as 'khurram'), but `[ListTypeDataID]` is probably a numerical value (i.e. an `INT`)

Comment: Your joins looks wrong in this case.

Comment: @Diado yeah you are right ListTypeData is a numerical value because according to my code i have to get this But the issue is now how to get rid of this Error.

Comment: Join using two columns of the same data type - in this case, using a column that represents a valid `[ListTypeDataID]` rather than a textual value is probably the way to go, but again without any DDL it's hard to know.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get rid of the error, but don't think it will give you correct output.

```
AS

    BEGIN

    SELECT 
        p.[ProductID] 
        ,l1.[Description] AS 'Category'
        ,l2.[Description] AS 'Supplier Name'
        ,p.[PurchasePrice] AS 'Purchase Price'
        ,p.[SalesPrice] AS 'Sales Price'
        ,l3.[Description] AS 'Sizes'

from [dbo].[Productss] p
INNER JOIN [dbo].[ListTypesData] l1 ON p.CategoryID) = l1.ListTypeDataID
INNER JOIN [dbo].[ListTypesData] l2 ON Convert(varchar(max),p.SupplierName) = Convert(varchar(max),l2.ListTypeDataID)
INNER JOIN [dbo].[ProductSizes] ps ON p.ProductID = ps.[ProductID]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[ListTypesData] l3 ON ps.[SizeID] = l3.ListTypeDataID


    END
```

Answer (score 0):

**p.SupplierName** is varchar & **l2.ListTypeDataID** is int thats why you are getting error

INNER JOIN [dbo].[ListTypesData] l2 **ON p.SupplierName = l2.ListTypeDataID**

Check All **Column Definitions** on which You're joining the tables.It should be same